# cleaning dirty memory from linux processes

Tags: linux, apache, memory, process, dirty-data

I'm running apache on my linux server and I notice many instances are taking over 100 MB memory a piece. I then ran process map and found out from one that 2/3 of the memory used by the process is dirty memory.

This is what the start of the result looks like:

```
root@server [/]# pmap -x 7752
7752:   /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
0000000000400000    1116     684       0 r-x--  httpd
0000000000716000      48      44      24 rw---  httpd
0000000000722000      20      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
00000000023d6000   62580   54348   54348 rw---    [ anon ]
00000000060f3000    1848    1828    1828 rw---    [ anon ]
00000000062c1000   37196   37120   37120 rw---    [ anon ]
00000031aba00000     128      88       0 r-x--  ld-2.12.so
00000031abc1f000       4       4       4 r----  ld-2.12.so
00000031abc20000       4       4       4 rw---  ld-2.12.so
00000031abc21000       4       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
```

Is there a way somehow to wipe out that dirty memory (Example: get rid of the anon entries) so that the apache process takes up more like 40 MB instead of over 100 MB? I want to avoid constantly restarting the server if possible.

Comment: Q: Is there a way to wipe out that dirty memory?  A: Sure.  Just use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).  Use a stiff brush and plenty of warm water :)  PS:that "dirty memory" is *nothing to worry about*.

Comment: "Dirty" is just a term that means it has been changed since the file was loaded from disk. For [anon] mappings there is no file so all of it is dirty.